# Como depurar una sub-carpeta de una carpeta main

Tags: python, visual-studio, vscode

Me pasa que cuando hago una depuración de un archivo que tengo en una sub-carpeta de una carpeta, siempre depura con el path de la carpeta original, por lo que si tengo un archivo tipo `.txt` y yo lo importo a un archivo python (todo esto dentro de mi sub-carpeta), debo poner todo el path..

Yo solo quiero importar mi archivo .txt con el path que sería solo su nombre, dado que estaría depurando mi sub-carpeta y no mi carpeta original.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi organización de carpeta y mi código bastante simple para mostrar de ejemplo, al momento de depurar me aparece este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio, si con vscode abro la carpeta 'Sub-carpeta' y depuro el archivo, me corre y bastante bien.

**La pregunta es** como configurar el depurador o el archivo .json para que me depure igual como si abriera la carpeta 'Sub-carpeta' en vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Al principio tenía el mismo problema que vos y lo solucione de varias formas dependiendo el proyecto que este desarrollando.
Hay algo que debés tener en cuenta que es el tipo de recurso que sea el archivo que queres abrir. Por ejemplo, los archivos temporales se guardan en una carpeta que todos conocemos %temp% no?
Basados en este principio si le ordenas a tu codigo que busque el txt en esa carpeta, estamos seguros que la va a encontrar.

Por ahí podes hacerte una carpeta en tu proyecto que contenga todos los txt, json,html y referir siempre a esa carpeta. O por otro lado si yu proyecto se basa solo en la subcarpeta2, enfocate en que todo lo que suceda con tu programa sea ejecutado a partir de esa carpeta como root.

Otra forma es hacer que mediante una UI importes documentos de texto, y que estos sean trasladados a una carpeta con un path que especifiques. y que cualquier cosa que necesites lo tengas ahí.
Podrías armarte un txt con los paths por defecto y que tu programa utilice estos como referencia. Hay muchas formas, todo depende de como quieras hacerlo.

Por eso existe la carpeta de descargas, temporales, system32, etc. Y todos los programas que utilicemos ya saben que ahí está lo que buscan. Espero te sirva y no olvides de puntuar. Saludos!